# 50's black & white movie with a white haired woman entering a flying saucer in a snow-covered landscape

Tags: story-identification, b-movies

Which '50s, vintage, black & white sci-fi movie has a white-haired woman entering a flying saucer, set in a snow covered landscape?  This is all I remember of the movie, but I’m pretty sure that this scene is at the end of the movie.

Being a B&W movie the woman was probably blonde.  She was going back to her home planet, probably Mars considering the era.  I think she/they crashed on Earth.

Comment: "white-haired" - As best as you can remember, was she light-haired (e.g. blonde) or white-haired? Was her hair "white" throughout the entire film or did something change it? Also, can you describe the spaceship at all...? ...Or, some plot points...?

Comment: Possibly The Flying Saucer... its 1950's features a blond woman and well, flying saucers obviously. Never actually watched it myself so can't say beyond this if its the one but its on youtube so take a look...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLUvpsyrb1c

Comment: I don't know the name of the film but I'm pretty sure I saw it on TV sometime between 1956-58. I think that all or most of the film takes place in a "snow-covered landscape" (like the Arctic). At the end of the film a man - one of the main characters, I imagine - is almost hypnotically attracted to walk to a flying saucer in the snow, lured by a beautiful white-haired (or at least light-haired) woman (human-looking alien). And if I remember correctly, there was very strange music playing during this scene ... maybe even a Theramin (an early electronic instrument).